# Verify isempty for user defined datatype in VBS

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, vbscript, uft, qtp-11.0

In UFT, my code return nothing (In watch it'll show as empty - user defined datatype)

And I am trying to validate returned value isempty or isnull But it's ignore the statements and going further.

Bellow is the snippet for understanding:

```
var t = Environment("VALUE1") '' VALUE1 not present in environment variable
if isempty(t) or isnull(t) then '' In watch t is holding empty with userdefined
msgbox "EMPTY"
else
msgbox "NOT EMPTY"
endif
```

in above example, `isempty(t)` is returning empty and it's executing msgbox "EMPTY".

My doubt is how to handle empty conditions if it's userdefined?
Mostly I am facing mentioned problem while working with environment variable or database.

Comment: Similar issue while fetching data from DB, evaluated statement is Empty with user defined type